# install gcc successful, but can't enable

Tags: gcc

I follow the [tutorial](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-gcc-compiler-on-centos-7/)  `install GCC` in `centos7`, install success, but can't enable.
here is the commands.

> sudo yum group install "Development Tools"
> sudo yum install centos-release-scl
> sudo yum install devtoolset-7
> scl enable devtoolset-7 bash
> gcc --version

And here is the running log:

```
-bash-4.2$ sudo yum group install "Development Tools"
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.ustc.edu.cn
 * centos-sclo-rh: mirror.lzu.edu.cn
 * centos-sclo-sclo: mirrors.ustc.edu.cn
 * epel: hkg.mirror.rackspace.com
 * extras: mirrors.ustc.edu.cn
 * updates: mirrors.ustc.edu.cn
Maybe run: yum groups mark install (see man yum)
No packages in any requested group available to install or update
-bash-4.2$ 
-bash-4.2$ 
-bash-4.2$ 
-bash-4.2$ 
-bash-4.2$ sudo yum install centos-release-scl
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.ustc.edu.cn
 * centos-sclo-rh: mirror.lzu.edu.cn
 * centos-sclo-sclo: mirrors.ustc.edu.cn
 * epel: hkg.mirror.rackspace.com
 * extras: mirrors.ustc.edu.cn
 * updates: mirrors.ustc.edu.cn
Package centos-release-scl-2-3.el7.centos.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
-bash-4.2$ 
-bash-4.2$ 
-bash-4.2$ 
-bash-4.2$ sudo yum install devtoolset-7
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.ustc.edu.cn
 * centos-sclo-rh: mirror.bit.edu.cn
 * centos-sclo-sclo: mirrors.ustc.edu.cn
 * epel: my.mirrors.thegigabit.com
 * extras: mirrors.ustc.edu.cn
 * updates: mirrors.ustc.edu.cn
Package devtoolset-7-7.1-4.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
-bash-4.2$ 
-bash-4.2$ 
-bash-4.2$ scl enable devtoolset-7 bash
bash-4.2$ 
bash-4.2$ 
bash-4.2$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have a mess with env paths.
Check files  `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` and remove old version path.

Last chance is to use direct/explicitly:

```
 source /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/enable
```